# Code-style question about passing return type to the generic method

Tags: java, generics, coding-style

I'm trying to pass return type to a generic method but I don't know whether such variant is considered to be ok or not:

```
RequestUtils.<String>getAttributeFromSession(AttributeName.SUBMISSION_TOKEN, request))
```

I was thinking about passing it as a parameter, but I feel like method invocation gets more hideous and less straightforward with every new argument passed with it:

```
RequestUtils.getAttributeFromSession(AttributeName.SUBMISSION_TOKEN, request, String.class))
```

The first one looks much clearer to me, but I guess it's subjective. **Are there any established coding style rules on such a case?**

Comment: Yes, and those rules are established by the Java compiler.  If you get a compiler warning about an unsafe or unchecked cast, you need to pass the class as an argument, and replace the unsafe cast with a call to the [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) method.